# Browser doesn't send Cookie when set trough cors-request

Tags: javascript, java, http, cookies, cors

i struggle with a Cookie that is set trough a CORS request.
Subsequentially the browser won't send the cookie.

I tried:

- adjusting cors-headers
- sending allowCredentials client-side
- SameSite=None flag

The Application (Browser) runs on the main domain (dev.mydomain.com/myApp)

and sent's a request (via a integrated WebComponent) to another domain (second.mydomain.com), that set's the cookie.

`POST https://second.mydomain.com/verifyToken => 200`

It responds:

```
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://dev.mydomain.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Authorization: Bearer eyJra...
Set-Cookie: refreshToken=eyJra...; Path=/refresh; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
```

The Request that should contain the cookie looks like this:

```
GET https://second.mydomain.com/refresh => 400

GET /refresh HTTP/1.1

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: second.mydomain.com
Origin: https://dev.mydomain.com
Referer: https://dev.mydomain.com/
```

The Response-Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 400
Date: Mon, 20 Nov 2023 12:05:41 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://dev.mydomain.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Can anyone give me a hint, why the cookie is not attached?

I also tried setting the Domain= Attribute in the cookie. But the default behaviour should pick the request-url as domain (in this case: second.mydomain.com)

The request is sent via axios rest-client

```
 axios.get(refreshPath, {withCredentials: true});
```

I would really appreciate any hints.

Best Regards
Alex

Comment: Was that first request, the POST, also made with `withCredentials` set to true?

Comment: if your server is sitting behind a reverse proxy like nginx, based on the inital server response (in your case 400), some headers might be stripped off. Nginx has some additinal config keyword 'always' like in here: https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487

Comment: @CBroe no, the first request is sent without "withCredentials=true", is this required ?

Comment: Yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials: _"In addition, this flag is also used to indicate when cookies are **to be ignored in the response**. The default is false. XMLHttpRequest responses from a different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @CBroe

The correct solution was, to use `withCredentials=true` with the initial request, that will lead to the response setting the Cookie!